Python: Module not found: Why did venv solve it?
I have the following project structure:
- project
  - src
    - module_a
      - foo.py
      - __init__.py
    - runner.py
    - constants.py
    - __init__.py

constants.py:
SOME_CONST = 5

foo.py:
from src.constants import SOME_CONST
class Foo:
    def some_func(self):
        ....

runner.py:
from src.module_a.foo import FOO

def main():
    Foo.some_func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I am trying to run python runner.py from the src folder, but it gave me a ModuleNotFound about src when foo.py was trying to import from src.constants import SOME_CONST.
I understand that the issue was the Python interpreter didn't recognise the src folder as a module, even though it has an __init__.py file.
After creating a venv virtual environment, the issue was resolved.
I have the following questions:

Why didn't the Python interpreter recognise the src folder as a module before creating a virtual environment?
Why did creating a virtual environment solve the issue?
How can I set up the project so that it will run without setting a virtual environment?


Don't use src as a package; consider it a "coincidence" that runner.py and your two top-level modules are in the same directory now.

@chepner why? if I have constants or utility functions that are shared across the project - shouldn't they be directly under src and used by all the modules (and that means I need src to be a module)?

You can store them in the directory src; that doesn't mean src defines a single Python package. runner.py is a script, not a module.

What was the error message? "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FOO'"?

@PeterMortensen "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'", and the error was thrown from foo.py from the line from src.constants import SOME_CONST.

You should not treat src as a package, but rather a directory that will be added to sys.path when you execute runner.py. Thus, constants and module_a are top-level modules, not submodules of a src package.
constants.py:
SOME_CONST = 5

foo.py:
from constants import SOME_CONST
class Foo:
    def some_func(self):
        ....

runner.py:
from module_a.foo import FOO

def main():
    Foo.some_func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

When you install to a virtual environment, module_a and constants should be installed under venv/lib, while runner.py should be installed under venv/bin, breaking your former assumption that runner.py and the modules all lived in the same directory.

Thanks! Should I add it to the sys.path in the runner.py script?
Also, if I want to containerize the project - should I have a command to add the src directory to sys.path in the dockerfile?

also, why did creating a venv solve the issue?

No, src should only be "relevant" to your source repository. runner.py could be installed in /usr/bin, and module_a and constants could be installed to /usr/lib/python/site-packages, for example.

How did you install the code into the virtual environment?

python -m venv C:\path_to_project\src.

That just creates a virtual environment, with your interpreter at C:\path_to_project\src\bin\python. You aren't really installing your code at all, but building a virtual environment around it. None of your code is in the right place.

I understand, but out of curiosity - why did it resolve the ModuleNotFound error?
